# Open Adobe Illustrator file via VB Script

Tags: vbscript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm new in Adobe Illustrator and VB script. I would like to know how to open Adobe Illustrator file using VB Script. I would like to automate few process of doing task.

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad I vote to reopen the question since it looks fine enough. It's about the basic knowledge in VBScript. It has a proper answer with the example of code and link to the documentation. SO doesn't have enough examples of VBScript code for Adobe Illustrator. It will be useful to have this question-answer on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Visual Basic so here is the quote from [the official documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AC-MUw8Pl7Vr-YXaxDNi2v4a_Vzih6xn/view?usp=drive_link) (p. 13):

```
Set appRef = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
Set docRef = appRef.Open("C:\temp\aFile.ai")
```

Comment: Tq alot for the help & it's really help me